# C++ Down-casting of a vector type

Tags: c++, downcast

Consider the code snippet below:

```
#include <vector>

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
std:vector<std:unique_ptr<Base>> baseVector;
```

I want to down-cast the `vector` to `vector<unique_ptr<Derived>>`

The naive approach would be:

1. iterating over the `baseVector`
2. for each element of type `Base`, `dynamic_cast` it to `Derived` class
3. add a casted element to the new vector of type `vector<unique_ptr<Derived>>`

Is there a simple way to down-cast the `baseVector` to `vector<unique_ptr<Derived>>` all together (one line)?

Comment: if you want one line, the best way imo is write a function to do it.

Comment: maybe range library can help though.

Comment: Downcasting is usually for chumps. Consider expanding the interface described by `Base` with virtual functions  so that the user needs not know or care what exact class they're holding.

Comment: You've to create a new vector. The value type of your desired vector is different so you cannot naively downcast the same vector. You may use std::transform to create new vector.

Comment: If every element in the vector is, in fact, `std::unique_ptr<Derived>`, then just use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Derived>>` to start with. If there are elements that aren't pointers to `Derived` then nothing you do can validly turn the vector into a vector of pointers to `Derived`. In short, this sound like a **design** problem, not a coding problem.